# Post value not getting the whole product name

Tags: php

I have this code which i want to extract unique product then post the values of the unique products to a different page.but its only pasting the searched value.

```
<?php include('header.php');?>
    <!-- end header -->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-3">
           </div>

        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="well well-sm " >
                    <strong>Category Title</strong>
                    <div class="btn-group" style="float:right;">
                        <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-themebtn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-1x"></i>List</a> 
                        <span style= "padding:5px;"href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-th fa-1x"></i>Grid</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                $query ="SELECT pname,pfeat,MIN(pprice) as minprice,MAX(pprice) as maxprice,count(*) as count FROM products where (pname like '%samsung%' AND conf=0) or (pmanu like '%samsung%' AND conf=0) GROUP BY pname ORDER BY count ;";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($query );
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    //extract row, this will make $row['firstname'] to just $firstname only
                    extract($row);
                ?>

                                    <?php $par=$row['pname'];?>
                                    <?php echo "<a href=pvendors.php?post=".$par.">".$row['pname']."</a>";?></h4>
                                <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                                <p>Retailers <?php echo $row['count'];?>
                                    </p><?php echo $row['pfeat'];?>
                                    </p>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                        <p class="lead">
                                            Price Range KSh.<?php echo $row['minprice'];?> - Ksh.<?php echo $row['maxprice'];?></p>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: can you explain in detail ? `unique products` means ? Not clear if you are facing issues with posting, extracting from php variable `$row` or fetching from mysql.

Comment: Where is your code of posting value?

Comment: I have a products table in DB with a field pname which contains the products name.Now unique just means the different products with the same name

Comment: <?php echo "<a href=pvendors.php?post=".$par.">".$row['pname']."</a>";?></h4> is what im using to post the value to a different page

Comment: Thanks alot.I found out that in order to pass the product name as a value in the url i need to encode it.